# Why these assignments produce different results?

Tags: f#

Why

```
let ab a b = a 5 + b
```

will produce

```
val ab : a:(int -> int) -> b:int -> int
```

and

```
let ab2 a b = a 5 +b
```

will produce

```
val ab2 : a:(int -> int -> 'a) -> b:int -> 'a
```

Why this one space between '+' and 'b' makes this difference?

Comment: In the expression `+b`, the `+` is interpreted as an [unary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) (taking only `b` as argument).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is all down to how the parser prioritises different syntactic options to avoid ambiguity.

`+` is both the binary addition operator and the unary "positive"<sup>1</sup> operator. `5 + b` is thus the application of addition to two arguments; but `+b` is the positive operator applied to some symbol `b`.

Thus

> ```
> let ab a b = a 5 + b
> ```

is parsed as:

```
let ab a b = (a 5) + b
```

with `a` being a function of one integer argument returning an int so it can be added to `b`; but

> ```
> let ab2 a b = a 5 +b
> ```

is parsed as:

```
let ab2 a b = a (5) (+b)
```

with `a` being a function of two arguments, with no way to infer the type it returns.

<sup>1</sup> I don't have an F# operator list to hand, so can't check the correct name. Edit: it appears I couldn't remember correctly: *[Arithmetic Operators (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469493.aspx)* :-).